# What is the distribution of conditional expectation of a function f(X) of the random variable X? i.e. E(f(X)|X)

Tags: random-variable, conditional-expectation

I have a continuous random variable `X` with a known PDF. I want to find the distribution of `f(X)` where `f(X)` is a function of X (e.g. `X^2+5X`). How do I find the distribution of `E(f(X)|X))`?

I know how to approach this when `X` is discrete. In this case, I would simply calculate `E(f(X)|X=t)` by summing over all possible values of `X=t` and then replace `t` by `X` to get the distribution of `E(f(X)|X)`.

Comment: It sounds like you need a formula for transforming a variable.  The hits at this search ought to help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=jacobian+change+score%3A1.

Comment: What do you mean by `E(f(X)|X))`. Also, what do you mean by lowercase `x` as opposed to the uppercase `X`?

Comment: lower case x was a typo and is fixed. By E(f(X)|X), I mean conditional expectation of f(X) given X. I think it should be f(X) but I just wanted to confirm. Then as @whuber mentioned, I will have to look at deriving distribution of function of a random variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for any random variable(discrete , continues and mixture) and Borel function, f

$E(f(X)|X)=f(X)$  so you just need to compute distribution of $f(X)$

so $E(X^2+X|X)=X^2+X$

note $E(f(X)|X)=f(X)$ is a random variable and  $E(f(X)|X=t)=f(t)$ is a number

this property ,$E(f(X)|X)=f(X)$ come from defination of conditional expectation and note that
$\sigma(f(X)) \subset \sigma(X)$